# Region bounded by $x=y^2$ and $x=y^3$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

What is meant by "the region bounded by $x=y^2$ and $x=y^3$"? The graphs of these two curves split the plane into 4 sections, but none of these are really bounded, they all kind of continue forever in some direction.

(In context, I was asked to find the volume of the solid under the surface $z=2x+y^2$ and above the aforementioned region)

Comment: It's referring to the bounded region between the segments connecting the two intersections at $(1,1)$ and $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It splits the plane into five regions. There's a sausage shape in the $[0,1]^2$ square. $x^3$ takes a little longer to get to $1$ than $x^2$ so it lies beneath $x^2$ from the common point $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

Comment: Whoa, this just made me realize something deep; an intersection is like a vertex of a shape, so if you have two curves and two intersections (here at x=0 and 1), you must get a closed shape! Same with three intersections and three curves, 4&4, 5&5, etc.